# How to implement a Style sheet in a data visualization class

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, gdi+

I try to construct a class (for a bigger personal project) which should draw a chart on a forms object. The last thing I got done was to put my "bad" flast made code into a class and cleaning it up, but then I realised that when working with GDI+ I often have to deal with many different pens and colors. Now Is there a possibility to build a class that holds a "style-sheet" that I can easlialy store in a .txt or .xml file and then read in and use? And does somebody has some ideas how to do that?
Felix

Comment: No. There are no style sheets for GDI+. It is a programmatic API only. You have to write code that creates the required drawing objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own class for storing colors and pens. Something like this.

```
public class Style
{
    public List<Color> Colors { get; set; }
    public List<Pen> Pens { get; set; }

    public void Save(string filename)
    {
        var xml = new XElement("style",
            this.Colors.Select(c => new XElement("color", c.ToArgb())),
            this.Pens.Select(p => new XElement("pen",
                new XElement("color", p.Color.ToArgb()),
                new XElement("width", p.Width))));

        xml.Save(filename);
    }

    public void Load(string filename)
    {
        var xml = XElement.Load(filename);

        this.Colors = xml.Elements("color")
            .Select(c => Color.FromArgb((int)c))
            .ToList();

        this.Pens = xml.Elements("pen")
            .Select(p => new Pen(
                Color.FromArgb((int)p.Element("color")),
                (float)p.Element("width")))
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Now you can easily save it to an xml file and read back.

```
var style = new Style();

style.Colors = new List<Color> {
    Color.FromArgb(10, 20, 30),
    Color.FromArgb(15, 25, 35)
};

style.Pens = new List<Pen> {
    new Pen(Color.Red, 5f),
    new Pen(Color.Green, 4f)
};

style.Save("style.xml");

var style2 = new Style();
style2.Load("style.xml");
```

Add code to read/write other `Pen` properties.

Comment: I will try it out! May need a bit time, thank you for helping me!